# Join table column into array and group by

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following tables:

```
JOBS TABLE
job_id     description
1          test
2          asdf

JOB_COSTCODES TABLE
job_id     cost_code_id
1          5
1          8
2          5
2          9
2          7
```

My goal is to select all of the jobs once, with all of the associated cost_code_ids as a comma separated string column.

```
job_id         description     cost_code_ids
1              test            5,8
2              asdf            5,9,7
```

I have the following SQL:

```
SELECT
    jobs.job_id, jobs.description,
        concat(',', job_costcodes.cost_code_id)
FROM
    jobs
JOIN
    job_costcodes ON job_costcodes.job_id = jobs.job_id
```

However, this returns the same job split into multiple rows with only a single cost_code_id in each row. I tried adding `GROUP BY jobs.job_id` at the end of the query, but that results in the error:

> Column 'jobs.description' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

STUFF and FOR XML can do the trick:

```
SELECT job_id, 
       description, 
       STUFF((
        SELECT ',' + cost_code_id
         FROM job_costcodes cc
         WHERE cc.job_id = j.job_id
         FOR XML PATH('')
        ), 1, 1, '') as cost_code_ids 
FROM JOBS j
```

Other ways to concatenate multiple rows into a single string [here](https://www.mytecbits.com/microsoft/sql-server/concatenate-multiple-rows-into-single-string#:%7E:text=You%20can%20concatenate%20rows%20into,the%20COALESCE%20to%20the%20variable.)